# Java relation b/w parent and child function calling mechanism

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am trying to understand the relation b/w parent and child function calling mechanism, but not got this one

```
class Parent {
    Parent() {
        greeting();//as we are not calling this on any object, by default it has Parent's greeting method
    }

    void greeting() {
        System.out.println("Greeting Parent");
    }
}

public class SuperConstructor extends Parent {
    public SuperConstructor() {
   //super(); //i know this
        greeting();
    }

    void greeting() {
        System.out.println("Greeting Child");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SuperConstructor();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:
Greeting Child, why ? how things work here ?
Greeting Child

---

OUTPUT (I expected)
Greeting Parent (reason: as the method is there in Parent class)
Greeting Child

Answer (score 3):

**Rule of Inheritance:** If there is overriding method exists in the child class, it will execute first, always ! And parent's method will be ignored.

**So, what happens here ?**

**>>** This `new SuperConstructor();` will execute first.

**>>** Which will create a new class of the child

**>>** Always remember, if there is no call to *super* constructor from your child constructor then your *JVM* will add one implicitly in child class constructor. And that will be the first line to execute.

**>>** So, your child constructor will make a call to `Super()`. And your parent consturctor will execute `greeting();` As child class has that method overriding, it will execute that instead of parent's. Why ? Because that is our inheritance rule say.

**>>** After that, child constructor execution will proceed as normal. next in line is `greeting();`, This will execute again Child's method. Why ? Because our rule of inheritance says so.

Comment: thanks! but I am not able to get Rule of Inheritance. I am looking for reasoning...how things work internally

Comment: @Naroji, Lets say, if parent has method `x()` and child has the same method. Then, in any normal circumstances, child method will be called. If you want to make a call to same parent method, then you need to use `super.x()`. You will have to read more on inheritance for all the rules.

Answer (score 1):

The reason who see `Greeting Child` as the Output is because the `greeting()` method in `SuperContructor` overrides the `greeting()` method of the `Parent` class. When a method Overrides another method, it completely replaces is. Please look at the following post which explains Overriding vs Hiding: [Overriding vs Hiding Java - Confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594052/overriding-vs-hiding-java-confused)

Answer (score 1):

This is because Parent is calling an overriden method. Make it private and you will get what you expect, private methods are not overridable.