# Can I use the final access modifier with public static void main(String args[]){ } method in Java?

Tags: java, program-entry-point, access-modifiers

```
class Test{

    public static final void main(String args[]){

    }

}
```

What are the other access modifiers can use with main() in Java 1.8?

Comment: What does your compiler say?

Comment: No compilation error

Comment: What are the other optional specifiers can use with main()  method in Java?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, but `final` does not make sense when used with a static method, since static methods cannot be overridden anyway.

By the way, final and static are not access modifiers. [Access modifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_modifiers) control which entity is allowed to access a method/field.

Comment: What we call static, final keyword in Java?

Comment: A non-access modifier :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `final` modifier. You can see that by simply compiling the program that you gave in your question.

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.3) has this to say about the `final` keyword as applied to methods:

> A method can be declared final to prevent subclasses from overriding or hiding it.

That is, if the method is an instance method (not static), it can be overridden, and `final` will prevent that. If a method is static, it can be hidden, and `final` will prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

`final` does not affect the method because it is already declared `static`, and hence it will not affect the program in any way. It only means that you cannot hide this method in a subclass.

Therefore if you wanted to make a class

```
class Hello2 extends Test {
....
}
```

you cannot make a `public static void main(String args[])` function in this class.

Comment: `static` methods cannot be overridden.

Comment: I checked on the compiler and it can actually hide the method in the superclass when the superclass method is not `final`. Are you referring to something else?

Comment: [`overriding` != `hiding`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594052/overriding-vs-hiding-java-confused).

Comment: @Pshemo, edited the answer for correctness. Thank you for bringing it into notice

Answer (score 0):

A `static` method **can** be `final`. As specified in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf), section 8.4.4.3, when a static method is final, it means that a subclass cannot "hide" it, i.e., define a method with the same name and same signature.

So, you can use `final`on your `main` method. The method will be usable as the main entry point of your program. Additionally, subclasses or your main class will not be able to hide it.