# inheritance in java does not work the way I expected

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following class:

```
public class X {
    public void A() {
        B();
    }

    private static void B() {
        System.out.println("111111111");
    }
}
```

Now I have the following inherited class Z:

```
public class Z extends X {

    private static void B() {
        System.out.println("22222222");
    }
}
```

now if I do

```
Z myClass = new Z();
Z.A();
```

I will get: 111111111 as a result. (Also, eclipse tells me that B() in the inherited class is never called).

Why? And how can I run the inherited B method?

Comment: static methods are not called polymorphically. They are statically bound at compilation time. Use an instance method. And don't make it private either: private methods are private, and thus can't be overridden. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The `B` methods are static**. When you call the method `A` it uses the implementation of class `B` (because that's where the method `A` is defined). Class `B` is not aware of the existence of class `Z` and cannot call a method of class `Z`.

Because the method is static, it's not overridden upon inheriting from `B`. Polymorphism only works with instances of a class. Static method does not play the polymorphism game and cannot be overridden.

Comment: That was what I afraid of. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: It's also not overridden because the method is `private`. A private method is not even seen in a subclass, so it can't ever be overridden. If you give it a different access modifier, then the fact that it is also `static` comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

Change **access modifier** of method from `private static` to `protected`

If you re-define base class non-static & non-private method in derived class, it's called **overriding**.

If you re-define base class static method in derived class, it's called method **hiding** or method **shadowing**.

You have done hiding rather overriding in your example.

Have a look at this [SE Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594052/overriding-vs-hiding-java-confused)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling X's inherited A method, and this calls its private B method.

`private` methods and attributes are not inherited.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changes it from private to protected but still the same behaviour. Any idea why?

Comment: That's not the reason. The reason is that the method is static.

Comment: @Avi Actually it is very much the reason, just as the fact that it is static is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are overriding method B() in class Z but method B() is not overridden here. Since B() is static so class A and class Z has there own method B(). Scope of all the Static methods and variables are class level not an object level.