# Static method hiding

Tags: java

Look at the code below :

```
class Marsupial {
    public static boolean isBiped() {
        return false;
    }

    public void getMarsupialDescription() {
        System.out.println("Value of this : " + this.getClass().getName() + " , Marsupial walks on two legs: " + isBiped());
    }
}

public class Kangaroo extends Marsupial {
    public static boolean isBiped() {
        return true;
    }

    public void getKangarooDescription() {
        System.out.println("Value of this : " + this.getClass().getName() + ", Kangaroo hops on two legs: " + isBiped());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Kangaroo joey = new Kangaroo();
        joey.getMarsupialDescription(); // Question here
        joey.getKangarooDescription();
    }

}
```

The output is :

```
Value of this : Kangaroo , Marsupial walks on two legs: false
Value of this : Kangaroo, Kangaroo hops on two legs: true
```

Now why in the call of getMarsupialDescription(), it will choose static method of Marsupial and not of Kangaroo especially when `this` points to `Kangaroo` ?

Comment: Static methods are never called virtually. They're always bound at compile-time. The point of static methods is that you don't *need* a `this` pointer to call it.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo thnx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding vs Hiding Java - Confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594052/overriding-vs-hiding-java-confused)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo does this mean static method hiding happens at compile time only as static binding will bind it at compile time ?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I believe you're correct. Static methods are always resolved at compile time, so if you used the same name in a subclass then that, too, would be resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put simply association of method call to the method body is type of binding. [[What is binding ?]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759384/what-is-binding-in-java-terminology) There are two types of binding: *Static Binding* that happens at compile time and *Dynamic Binding* that happens at runtime.

**Static Binding or Early Binding**

The binding which can be resolved at compile time by compiler is known as static or early binding. The binding of static, private and final methods is compile-time. Why? The reason is that the these method cannot be overridden and the type of the class is determined at the compile time. Lets see an example to understand this:

```
class Human{
   public static void walk()
   {
       System.out.println("Human walks");
   }
}
class Boy extends Human{
   public static void walk(){
       System.out.println("Boy walks");
   }
   public static void main( String args[]) {
       /* Reference is of Human type and object is
        * Boy type
        */
       Human obj = new Boy();
       /* Reference is of HUman type and object is
        * of Human type.
        */
       Human obj2 = new Human();
       // At compile time it gets decided which body of method it will call
       obj.walk(); 
       obj2.walk();
   }
}
```

Why at compile time ? As it is static.
Static binding is done by Type of reference not by the type of object.

**Output:**

```
Human walks
Human walks
```

Similarly in the code in question above - isBiped() static method is linked to the body of the method during compile time only. Hence it calls Marsupial isBiped().

[What is static and dynamic binding ?](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/what-is-static-and-dynamic-binding-in.html)

[Source of above answer](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-static-dynamic-binding/)