# What is a java binding? Is it same as language binding? What do you mean by 'people can use former json protocol using java bindings?

Tags: java, selenium

I was reading the following site: https://medium.com/@juanba48/selenium-4-is-now-w3c-compliant-what-does-this-mean-ceb44de2d29b and have difficulty understanding terminologies like java bindings, language bindings and how different language can be used to write selenium code. I searched a lot but haven't found satisfactory answers. Could someone explain in layman terms? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**java binding:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49759863/6793637

> Most generally, "binding" is about associating an identifier to
> whatever it identifies, be it a method, a variable, or a type.

**Language binding**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25875/6793637

> Bindings are wrapper libraries that bridge between two programming
> languages so that a library that was written for one language can also
> be implicitly used in another language.
>
> For example, libsvn is the API for Subversion and was written in C. If
> you want to access Subversion from within Java code you can use
> libsvn-java. libsvn-java depends on libsvn being installed because
> libsvn-java is a mere bridge between the Java programming language and
> libsvn, providing an API that merely calls functions of libsvn to do
> the real work.

**how different language can be used to write selenium code**

If you see how driver works,

[image]

It act as a intermediate between , client and browser.

The driver for each browser are different with different languages and technologies ,

THe methods in the driver are ecxposed through an API and you have different libraries in different languages that can talk to this exposed api .

So from code you call this API , and api sends instruction to driver, which talks to browser , browser send result to driver driver sends back to client through API.

> eg elem.click() tells the api to invoke the code for click () , the
> driver execute the code and sends command to browser to click, and
> browser returns status to driver and driver returns the status back to
> client through the API